# EG getting restarted when ESB tries to fetch data from an external system over TCPIP connection for more than 59 times

Tags: tcp, ibm-integration-bus

One  ESB SOAP application which is developed on IIB 10 is connecting to an external system, say system A, over TCPIP protocol.System A has exposed many services and ESB application will put the request on the TCPIP server and listen to the same server for the responses.Request is put via TCPClientOutput node and response is received via TCPClientReceive.ESB application has to fetch the data depends on the length of output response.The responses will be obtained as bit streams and in each stream, indication of next response will be there. For a particular service exposed by the system A, when ESB application tries to fetch the data for more than 59 times(count varies,minimum count observed is 59), the EG is getting restarted.Please find the application error log below:

```
Error Code :4374; Error Text :CallObjectMethod() failed calling toString
```

Comment: Good problem description, but a few details are missing. Which version of IIB are you using? Can you post the entire error message from IIB (that does not look like the usual IIB error message format). Did you find any abend files in the IIB working directory?

Comment: I'm using IIB version 10.There were no abend files generated.In broker.log, I could find the below error just above the log lines for stopping the EG                                        BIP2121E: The thread bootstrap code caught an unhandled exception on thread number '8966' with name 'com.esb.SoapAdapter'.
BIP4374S: An unexpected exception has occurred in the Java API framework.                         The same application is working for normal cases, but when the TCP fetch is exceeding 59 count only, EG is getting restarted

Answer (score 1):

> BIP2121E: The thread bootstrap code caught an unhandled exception on thread number '8966' with name 'com.esb.SoapAdapter

That sounds like an error in the SOAP framework (so not necessarily connected with TCP/IP at all). I suggest that you open a ticket with IBM, as BIP2121 is often the symptom of an uncaught exception in the IIB product.